# Can't create a Fluid App due to "Invalid Certificate"

Tags: macos, safari, ssl, fluid.app

I am trying to create a Fluid App for a work intranet. It says the certificate is invalid, is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 7):

Developer of [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com) here. Yes, you can fix this now by:

1. Visit the page in Safari
2. Expand the "Invalid Certificate" Dialog
3. Select "Always Trust" option

Now you can it works in Fluid too

[image]